# Utilities.parseCsv could not parse text with ";" delimiter

Tags: csv, google-apps-script

I am trying to import a CSV file into my sheet using Google Apps Script, however it has a custom delimiter. `;`
I am trying to run this code:

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("RAW Prisliste");
var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Forhandlerprisfil_web.csv").next();
var csv = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv, ";");
```

And then paste it into the sheet, but it gives me the error `Could not parse text.` when it reaches the last line shown above.
I don't understand why this is. Help?

Comment: Can you please share the file you are trying to parse? The code works fine with a semicolon separated file I created. Thanks

Comment: You can post a section of the input file into a code section in your question.  After posting selection it all and press control K

Comment: Does the CSV file use `CRLF` or `LF` for end of line?

Comment: Log the output of csv using `Logger.log(csv)`, right before the last line. Does it log what you expect?

Comment: @ZektorH I am not allowed to share the actual file, but this is the header of the CSV:
`Produktnr;ProducentVarekode;Status;Varemærke;Varenavn;Nettovægt;Stregkode;htmlsti;Billedsti;Produkthovedgruppe;Produktundergruppe;Energiklasse;VejlUdsalgspris;ForhandlerNettoPris;Kolli1;Kolli1Pris;Kolli2;Kolli2Pris;Lager;Fjernlager;LevDato;EUintrastatNo;`

@MiMi When I do that, it works fine for some reason.

@IMTheNachoMan I have no idea. How do I check for that?